# How to listen to touch/click event on any object which is being animated by ValueAnimator

Tags: android, android-animation

I am going through `"BouncingBalls"` api guide provided by google. I wonder whether there is any way to listen to touch or click event to the ball object created dynamically. Actually I am trying to use  `ValueAnimator` class for a simple game which requires user to touch the object. There are `many objects` of diffrent types ( for example balls of different radii ) and these objects can either be static images from drawable or can be drawn at run time.
Is there any way to detect the touch to the balls ?
Here is my sample ValueAnimator object

```
ValueAnimator simpleAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myObject,"y",startY,endY)
simpleAnimation.setDuration(something)
simpleAnimation.setInterpolator(something)
ValueAnimator startAnim = new AnimatorSet()
startAnim.play(simpleAnimation);
```

Now,  I want to do some stuff when user touches myObject.Till now , All I know is this

```
    simpleAnimation.addListener()
```

but none of the paramaters suffices to touch event handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `ShapeHolder`, add a method to check whether touch point is inside of the `ShapeHolder`.

```
class MyShapeHolder extends ShapeHolder {

    public MyShapeHolder(ShapeDrawable s) {
        super(s);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private boolean isTouchInside(final float x, final float y) {
        if (x < getX() + getWidth() / 2 &&
            x > getX() - getWidth() / 2 &&
            y < getY() + getHeight() / 2 &&
            y > getY() - getHeight() / 2) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then in `onTouchEvent`, add the following code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); ++i) {
        MyShapeHolder shapeHolder = balls.get(i);
        if (shapeHolder.isTouchInside(event.getX(), event.getY()))
            Log.d("TEST", "TOUCH ON BALL " + i);
        }
    }
```

Add you can also create a listener for `ShapeHolder`, like `OnShapeTouchListener`. It will be a good practice for you. :)